# C++ map - expression must be an integral constant expression

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dictionary, stl, std

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::map<std::string, int> foo;
foo["bar"] = 1;
```

Why do I get the error "expression must be an integral constant expression" in visual studio 12?

I can't work this one out...

Comment: Compiles perfectly fine for me. VS2013.

Comment: [Works with gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ef2da95029f6919).

Comment: @Steve Then your compiler is broken. Statements must go in functions.

Comment: @juanchopanza I added a main function ... The comment isn't helpful.

Comment: @Steve gcc isn't broken. `foo["bar"] = 1;` is a statement and it must go in a function.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Just a nit, but, while it's true that a statement must go in a funciton, that's because if it's in a function it's regarded syntactically as a statement. And so one can't use the *syntactical form* as a criterion for where something is admitted. In particular, a declaration of a variable is a statement (an example of a block declaration) when it's inside a function, but it's just a declaration (and permitted) outside of a function --  thus if you look at its syntactic form and say "hey, that's a statement, must be inside a function" you get the wrong conclusion.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I really do think we should resurrect the terminology from BCPL, the ancestor of C which is ancestor of C++, where non-declaration statements were called **commands**. That term was very useful in pre-C99 C, because declarations had to come before commands in blocks. And it's still very useful for discussing the issue at hand: *commands have to be in functions*. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That's a good point and I do find the current C and C++ terminology lacking in this respect. Thanks for nit-picking, it is good to step back and think of these things carefully every now and then.

Answer (score 3):

You need to place the code inside a function.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

void xyz()
{
   std::map<std::string, int> foo;
   foo["bar"] = 1;
}
```

I verified VS 2013 has a problem otherwise, but it works when inside a function. As others have noted, most statements aren't allowed outside of a function.